# Getting Google Map Location URL to a text box

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm very new to Google maps, In my project, there is a requirement like this.

There is link to open up Google map, when the user clicks on the link, Google Map will appear and when he select a location form the map, URL of that location should fill in to a text box,

Is there a way to do like that? Because I need to save it in the DB and have to use in a Web Service.

Any suggestions also welcome.

Comment: Are you asking for a link to a location on http://maps.google.com?  Like [this](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=New+York,+NY&hl=en&ll=40.704066,-74.003906&spn=0.399773,0.609741&sll=40.85968,-74.157769&sspn=0.199418,0.304871&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=11) or are you looking for a Google Maps API map (on your own domain)?

Comment: As i Explain in my question, just wanted to open up google map when click on link and, once user select a location from the map, populate a text box with the url of the location selected.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the google's documentation on events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   //event.latLng is the lat long of the click's location
   //At this point you could do a document.getElementById("someId").value= ... to cahnge the text box
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not the exact answer to your question, but since you've just start with google-maps + db + webservice maybe you'll better start with this official tutorial
[Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)